# How to decipher this string from sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I have this string in a table.

```
[0-9]+(\*+)? ?([0-9]+)?(\*+)? ?([0-9]+)?
```

I understand that 0-9 means any number from 0 to 9, but the rest... what is the difference between [] and (), what does ? or + or / or *  mean? What is the space between?

```
? ?
```

How do I decipher it? What is this called? Are all these wild cards?

Comment: Look into regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [regrex](http://regexr.com/) (see [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression))

> Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations
>   in strings. These
>   patterns are used with the exec and test methods of RegExp, and with
>   the match, replace, search, and split methods of String.
>   [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

[RANGE] is like [a-z] or [SINGLE CHARACTERS] like [abc]

(MATCH_SET) in your result

Example Text "My lazy dog sleeps"
with regex `/(lazy) (dog)/` matches

```
Resultset 0 = lazy dog
Resultset 1 = lazy
Resultset 2 = dog
```

With
    `?/+///*`
I think you posted something wrong.

Comment: I meant ? or + or / or *